# Whatsapp message automated reply

Tags: python

I am trying to create automate a reply on whatsappweb every-time a selected person messages me. Every time i run the code it doesn't stop

```
user = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//span[@title = "{name}"]')
user.click()
usrname = 'Mum'
msg_box = driver.find_element_by_class_name('_13mgZ')
kiki = ""
##while True:
##   if kiki != None:
##       break

kiki = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH(f"//span[.='{usrname}']"))))

kiki = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//span[.='{usrname}']")
while True:
    if kiki == driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//span[.='{usrname}']"):
            for i in range(count):

                msg_box.send_keys(msg)
                driver.find_element_by_class_name('_3M-N-').click()
                time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: You have a `while True:` that will run forever. What is the ideal solution?

Comment: If you would like to stop `while True` loop (which will run forever), then there should be inner condition which will do `break`. Otherwise, loop will never stop.

Comment: Main goal is to send 'usrname' i.e. Mum every time she replies on our group chat. if I take while True: out,  the program stop and doesn't reply to future messages.